# column reference is ambiguous sql error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to join 4 different table to calculate item revenue depending on some conditions ,I will write sql query after I'm able to build the right view using 4 tables ...below is the query for the view and I'm getting ambiguous column error for ik...can someone please explain why?
Thanks for your help!

```
select top 5 g.*
from (
    select *
    from (
        (
            select a.ik
                ,b.upc as upc
                ,b.class
                ,a.units
            from Tbl1 a
            join TBL2 b
                on a.ik = b.ik
            ) c join Tbl3 d
            on c.ik = d.ik
        ) e
    join Tbl4 f
        on e.ik = f.ik
    ) g
```

Comment: You are using `select *` with a `join` connecting multiple tables.  Some of the tables have duplicate column names.

Comment: You are joining the results in `e` to `Tbl4` and doing a `Select *` on that result, which will give two `ik` values.  Change the `Select *` to only pull back the values you care about.  A side note - I'm positive your query can be simplified, but I haven't the slightest idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you try using CTE or temp table instead?  In my opinion, it is better to troubleshoot and easier for everyone to read.

Answer (score 3):

you can run select * when you have join ,
you should put the table alias

```
select top 5 g.*
from (
    select *
    from (c.*,b.*
        (
            select a.ik
                ,b.upc as upc
                ,b.class
                ,a.units
            from Tbl1 a
            join TBL2 b
                on a.ik = b.ik
            ) c join Tbl3 d
            on c.ik = d.ik
        ) e
    join Tbl4 f
        on e.ik = f.ik
    ) g
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to follow what this query is doing, but since you are using sub-selects, try aliasing `ik` in the select part of each of the queries where it is included in the select(i.e. `select a.ik as 'aliased_ik'`).

You should also not use `.*`, in the outer select query, but rather use each of the individual column names. If `ik` is in the outer select query, you should alias that as well.